# Wrap a row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to create a chatbot. I will be very honest, UI is not my forte. I am working on the backend of the chatbot as in the logic part, but for testing I need a proper working UI. So, I opted for easier to use winforms. I created a single column DataGridView and all the text written in a textbox at the bottom part of the chat window will appear as DataGridView rows. The winform is anchored to grow in all directions. So, when I load the exe, it shows as a miniature window, when I maximize it, the DataGridView portion and the textbox grow accordingly.

When I type a long string and the winform is not in a maximized state, the text is not wrapped in the row in the visible area. It extends horizontally and so obviously not visible in the screen. When I maximize the window, I can see the text. When I give a veryyy long string and maximize the window, only that much of the string is shown in the row as it can fit in the screen size.

What I want to do: I want the text to wrap automatically in the rows, so that, irrespective of whether my window is maximized or minimized, I can see the entire string in the window in a wrapped format.

What I have tried:

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

Comment: @Natrium that question refers to a textbox, this one to a datagridview, which is very different.

Comment: It works in my test program. Can it be that you override the DefaultCellStyle.WapMode somewhere? check this for instance in your form load, using linq; dataGridView1.Rows.SelectMany(row => row.Cells).All(cell => cell.InheritedStyle == DataGridViewTriState.True);

Comment: The thing is, when the words are separated with spaces, it wraps, but if its a single long string then wrapping doesn't work.

Comment: `DataGridViewTextBox` performs wrapping using word-break. It means if you have a long text, the break will just apply at the end of words. Based on your requirement, you need character-break when word wrapping. To do so, you need to create a custom cell and perform character-break wrapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataGridViewTextBox` performs wrapping using word-break. It means if you have a long text, the break will just apply at the end of words. Based on your requirement, you need character-break when word wrapping. To do so, you need to create a custom cell and perform character-break wrapping this way:

- Override `GetPreferredSize` method to calculate the height of Cell/Row based on character break word wrapping. To so so you can use `Graphics.MeasureString` method.
- Override `Paint` method to draw the wrapped string with character break using `Graphics.DrawString` method.

You can perform these settings:

- To use the width of `DataGridView` for your column, you should set it's `AutoSizeMode` to `Fill`. This way, your column width will fill the grid and will be change its size according to grid size. Also if you had more than one column, you can set `FillWeight` to control the percent of column size relative to other columns.
- To wrap the text in column you should set `DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode` of the column to `DataGridViewTriState.True`.
- To make the rows auto-size you should set `AutoSizeRowMode` of `DataGridView` to `DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells`.
- Register the custom cell which we created as `CellTemplate` of the column.

**MyDataGridViewTextBoxCell**

This cell performs text-wrapping using character-break instead of word break.

```
public class MyDataGridViewTextBoxCell:DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    protected override Size GetPreferredSize(Graphics graphics, 
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, int rowIndex, Size constraintSize)
    {
        if(cellStyle.WrapMode== DataGridViewTriState.True && this.RowIndex>=0)
        {
            var value= string.Format("{0}", this.FormattedValue);
            using (var g = this.OwningColumn.DataGridView.CreateGraphics())
            {
                var r =  g.MeasureString(value, cellStyle.Font, this.OwningColumn.Width )
                          .ToSize();
                r.Width += cellStyle.Padding.Left + cellStyle.Padding.Right;
                r.Height += cellStyle.Padding.Top + cellStyle.Padding.Bottom;
                return r;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return base.GetPreferredSize(graphics, cellStyle, rowIndex, constraintSize);
        }
    }
    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, 
        Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, 
        object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, 
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, 
        DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, 
        DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, 
            formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, 
            paintParts & ~ DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);
        graphics.DrawString(string.Format("{0}", formattedValue), 
            cellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, cellBounds);
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
public class Model
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

BindingList<Model> list = new BindingList<Model>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var column1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    column1.CellTemplate = new MyDataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    column1.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    column1.DataPropertyName = "Text";
    column1.DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    column1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
    column1.HeaderText = "Text";
    column1.Name = "column1";

    dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column1);

    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list.Add(new Model() { Text = textBox1.Text });
}
```

Comment: Awesome.. It worked brilliantly. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.